# Order state is updated to closed after creating an invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, order-status, order-state

This is my code for creating a `pending` invoice:

```
if ($order->canInvoice()) {
    $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
    $invoice->register();
    $invoice->save();
    $transactionSave = $this->transaction->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
    $transactionSave->save();
}
```

I also have virtual products, so no shipment will be created. My issue is, that after creating the invoice programmatically, the order state and status is updated to `closed`. Not sure why?
It should remain `processing`.
Do yo have any ideas why or any suggestion are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Which payment method did you use?

Comment: credit cards from Adyen

Answer (score 0):

Even I Had the same issue with online payments so for that all we have to do is capture the invoice. Since I missed that line I was facing the same issue

```
    $invoice->capture();
```

```
if (!$order->hasInvoices()) {
    $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
    $invoice->register();
    $invoice->setTransactionId($transactionDetails['txnid']);
    $invoice->capture();
    $order->addRelatedObject($invoice);
    if ($order->getShipmentsCollection()->count()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('complete')->setStatus('complete');
            $order->addStatusToHistory(Order::STATE_COMPLETE, 'Order has been paid.', true);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
        }
    } else {
        $order->setState($order::STATE_PROCESSING)->save();
        $order->setStatus($order::STATE_PROCESSING)->save();
        $order->addStatusToHistory(Order::STATE_PROCESSING, 'Order has been paid.', true);
    }
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);
}
```